# How to tie two tuples?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

How to tie two tuples? For example

```
std::tuple<int, char> a;
std::tuple<double> b;
```

Is it possible to write a function `my_tie(a, b)` that returns `std::tuple<int&, char&, double&>` so that after

```
my_tie(a, b) = make_tuple(1, 'a', 3.14);
```

`a == std::tuple<int, char>{1, 'a'}` and `b == std::tuple<double>{3.14}`. That is, the `my_tie` function (different from std::tie) first unties the tuples and then ties all elements together.

Comment: And what exactly did you want?

Comment: `tie<decltype(a), decltype(b)>(a, b)`? What's the use case?

Comment: `std::tie` flattens the type for a reason: It's easier to use it thus, and no less general.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? As currently written, it's impossible to understand whether you're claiming that `tie` flattens the `tuple`s ([it doesn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e985b7792db0c5a)), or you *want it to* flatten them.

Comment: @Praetorian I want to build my tie function (different from std::tie), which will first untie the tuples and then tie all elements together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Updated Dec 29, 2014 to use `std::index_sequence_for`)

Here's a solution that uses C++14's index sequences:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <class... T1, class... T2,
          std::size_t... i, std::size_t... j>
auto tie_helper(std::tuple<T1...>& t1, std::tuple<T2...>& t2,
                std::index_sequence<i...>, std::index_sequence<j...>) {
    return std::tuple<T1&..., T2&...> {std::get<i>(t1)..., std::get<j>(t2)...};
}

template <class... T1, class... T2>
auto tie(std::tuple<T1...>& t1, std::tuple<T2...>& t2) {
    typedef std::index_sequence_for<T1...> s1;
    typedef std::index_sequence_for<T2...> s2;
    return tie_helper(t1, t2, s1{}, s2{});
}
```

Comment: `std::index_sequence_for<T...>` is showing some sort of error if T is an empty pack with clang-Apple LLVM version 7.0.0, while `std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...<T>` works fine for all cases.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly more general than @Brian's version:

```
// construct a tuple of Ts&... from a tuple of Ts...
template <class... T, std::size_t... i>
auto to_tuple_ref_helper(std::tuple<T...>& t, std::index_sequence<i...>) {
    return std::tuple<T&...> {std::get<i>(t)...};
}

template <class... T>
auto to_tuple_ref(std::tuple<T...>& t) {
    return to_tuple_ref_helper(t, std::index_sequence_for<T...>());
}

// and a tuple containing a single reference from all other types
template <class T>
auto to_tuple_ref(T& t) {
    return std::tuple<T&>{t};
}

// tuple_cat the tuples of references together
template <class... Ts>
auto flattening_tie(Ts &...args) {
    return std::tuple_cat(to_tuple_ref(args)...);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11a206bfcf1def0b).